# Excessive durations in SQL Server Trace

Tags: sql-server

Am wondering why some of my durations in SQL Server Profiler are coming out unreasonably huge. I am monitoring a web page (turn on profiler, click button, wait for response, stop profiler, dump to trace table). The I find the ClientProcessId of my process and select only those entries.

The entire process runs about 10-12 seconds. Most of the Durations in the trace make sense, being 1-2 or maybe 3 seconds. Bu there is a small number of entries that are just off the wall reporting durations like 720+ seconds (742098 milliseconds). Does not make sense to me that SQL server would be reporting that something ran o for 720 seconds within a 12 second period.

Tried googling a bit but not getting item which seem to match my situation. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible for some events.

For events like: SQL:BatchCompleted, RPC:Completed and others.

In these case, in your period, you see the end of events started before your trace.

Just look on start time to have a confirm.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and sorry it took so long to come around to accepting it. The project requiring the trace info did not go forward, but very glad to have the mystery explained!